# Ajax live search of xml document

Tags: php, ajax, xml

I'm building a employee directory with over 4k employees. The method im using works great on a few hundred but takes way to long to search the over 4k employees. I'm looking for a way to speed this up or a better way to do the search altogether.

This is the ajax running on the main php page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","empSearch.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This is the php that searches the xml document and formats the results.

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('find_search_inc.xml');

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('emp');

$q=$_GET["q"];

if (strlen($q)>=1)
{
$hint="";

for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
  {
  $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('fname');
  $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('lname');
  $w=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('location');
  $p=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('position');
  $id=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('id');

  if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
    {
    if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)||stristr($z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {   
        $hint="<div class='emp'> <dl class='empInfo'>
        <dd class='info'><strong>".$y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue." ".$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."</strong></dd>
        <dd class='info'><img src='images/emailIcon.png' />email@leprinofoods.com</dd>
        <dd class='info'><img src='images/phoneIcon.png' />". $p->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</dd>
        <dd class='info'><img src='images/briefcaseIcon.png' />". $id->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</dd>
        <dd class='info'><img src='images/locationIcon.png' />". $id->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</dd>
        <dd class='empImage'><img src='images/default.png' /></dd>

        </dl></div>";
        }
      else
        {
         $hint=$hint ."<div class='emp'> <dl class='empInfo'>
        <dd class='info'><strong>".$y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue." ".$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."</strong></dd>
        <dd class='info'><img src='images/emailIcon.png' /> email@leprinofoods.com</dd>
        <dd class='info'><img src='images/phoneIcon.png' /> ". $p->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</dd>
        <dd class='info'><img src='images/briefcaseIcon.png' />". $id->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</dd>
        <dd class='info'><img src='images/locationIcon.png' />". $id->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</dd>
        <dd class='empImage'><img src='images/default.png' /></dd>
        </dl></div>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
if ($hint=="")
  {
  $response="Sorry that employee was not found.";
  }
else
  {
  $response=$hint;
  }
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Do not paste live code here. Instead, re-write a code-example from scratch that demonstrates the isolated, concrete issue with as little code and data as necessary so that it can be easily reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use XML

First of all use the X in ajax! So don't send HTML hidden in plain text, but your data in XML

#### Split up AJAX Requests

Split up the ajax requests, maybe use pages to show the data. So less data is transported.

#### Use a database

Your biggest problem is that you don't use a database! XML files will be fast for like 100 entries but incredible slow compared to real databases like [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). After all you are reading in that file for every request.